# Auto Conversion of Structs to Dicts in Cython

Tags: cython

So, if you've got a header file.

```
%%file test.h

struct mystruct{
  int i;
  int j;  
};
```

And then you wrap it in Cython:

```
cdef extern from "test.h" nogil:
  struct mystruct:
    int i
    int j
```

And some function that returns back out to Py:

```
def spit_out_dict():
  return mystruct(5,10)
```

Cython correctly automatically generates a dict wrapper. However, when I wrap the original C header in a namespace, I haven't been able to get get Cython to still generate the dict wrapper correctly, something along these lines:

```
%%file test2.h

namespace outerspace{
struct mystruct{
  int i;
  int j;  
};
}
```

And Cython/Python:

```
cdef extern from "test2.h" namespace "outerspace" nogil:
  struct mynewstruct:
    int i
    int j

def spit_out_dict():
  return mynewstruct(5,10)
```

This won't compile -- lots of namespace complaint errors -- anyone experienced this before?

Comment: This is untested (so may be wrong) but try adding `# distutils: language = c++` to the top of the Cython file. Alternatively, call the Cython command with `--cplus`. (I think what's happening is that it's just C getting confused by C++ syntax and you need to tell it to use C++).

Comment: My tests are already passing in c++ flag sadly =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that Cython seems to only expect namespaces to be used with `cppclass`. For structs, it generates some functions but just copies the full namespaced name in, causing errors:

```
static PyObject* __pyx_convert__to_py_outerspace::mystruct(struct outerspace::mystruct s);
                  ^
py_bit.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* __pyx_pf_6py_bit_spit_out_dict(PyObject*)’:
py_bit.cpp:721:15: error: ‘__pyx_convert__to_py_outerspace’ has not been declared
```

where it's trying to create a function called `__pyx_convert__to_py_<classname>`. (I think this might be worth submitting a bug report for.)

The trick in such circumstances is usually to lie to Cython. I create three files:

```
// test2.hpp
namespace outerspace{
struct mystruct{
  int i;
  int j;  
};
}
```

,

```
// test2_cy.hpp - a wrapper file purely for Cython's benefit
#include "test2.hpp"

using outerpsace::mystruct;
```

and the cython file

```
cdef extern from "test2_cy.hpp": # (I didn't test with "nogil", but it's probably fine...)
  struct mynewstruct:
    int i
    int j

def spit_out_dict():
  # for some reason using "return mystruct(5,10)" doesn't work, but this does...
  cdef mystruct a = mystruct(5,10)
  return a
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in Cython, fixed at https://github.com/cython/cython/commit/fa946e8435a4dcc3497fc7b0f4e87256d40844ba